# How to set breakpoint in child process after set follow-fork mode child?

Tags: c, linux, debugging, gdb

I want to set a breakpoint for a child process [Task B] which is invoked by another process [Task A].

I used set follow-fork mode child to switch from parant process to child. However, GDB is not stopping in child task rather it runs and return to the Task B.

Is there a way I can stop in child task and debug it?

Comment: Are you sure the child executes the code path where the breakpoint is set?

Answer (score 1):

I have found this resource to be useful in the past for things of this nature http://www.delorie.com/gnu/docs/gdb/gdb_26.html

And of course as the first comment to your question suggests, double check that the breakpoint is actually in the child execution path.

Comment: @NikolaiNFetissov - Yes indeed

Comment: Link is broken. Web Archive link is [Debugging with GDB](https://web.archive.org/web/20130301041129/http://www.delorie.com/gnu/docs/gdb/gdb_26.html), corresponding new link is [Forks (Debugging with GDB)](https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb.html/Forks.html).